# Copy row to another sheet based on value in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy a row of data onto another sheet based on a value in that row.  The value is 0 and will always be found in Column J of the origin sheet. I want columns A - N copied to the second sheet. I found this script which copies the entire row.  The problem is I need to preserve any data that was previously entered onto the second (destination) sheet in columns O - AZ. Unfortunately, the script below pastes the entire row to the second (destination) sheet and any data that was entered in columns O - AZ is lost.

```
Sub MyMacro()

    Dim i As Long, iMatches As Long

    Dim aTokens() As String: aTokens = Split("0", ",")

    For Each Cell In Sheets("AMI").Range("J:J")

        If Len(Cell.Value) <> 0 Then

            For i = 0 To UBound(aTokens)

                If InStr(1, Cell.Value, aTokens(i), vbTextCompare) Then

                    iMatches = (iMatches + 1)

                    Sheets("AMI").Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Sheets("AMI Fallout").Rows(iMatches + 1)

                End If

            Next

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel macro, to copy and paste a cell value based on another cell value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517471/excel-macro-to-copy-and-paste-a-cell-value-based-on-another-cell-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are copying a **complete** row with code like:

```
Sub dural()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(11).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(17)
End Sub
```

To copy only **part** of the row, use something like:

```
Sub dural2()
    Set r1 = Intersect(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(11), Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:N"))
    Set r2 = Intersect(Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(13), Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("A:N"))
    r1.Copy r2
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked well.  I am grateful for the excel wizards here that are willing to share.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question, this code will only copy columns A:n of the specified row to the *AMI Fallout* worksheet.

```
Sheets("AMI").Cells(Cell.Row, 1).Resize(1, 14).Copy Sheets("AMI Fallout").Cells(iMatches + 1, 1)
```

I'm concerned about how you are determining a positive criteria for the row transfer. It looks like you are trying to `Split` a *0* on a comma (which doesn't exist) then loop through a single value array and check for partial matches on a *0*. The partial matches produced by `InStr` are the most disconcerting.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
Sheet1.Rows(cell.row) = sheet2.Rows(Cell.row).Value
```